# Android Studio adding custom intentions for Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ide

I can't find anywhere how to add a custom menu intention in Android Studio for Flutter.

I know it can be done because some plugins expand the default set of intentions (like in the example below I have some extra Bloc intentions).

[image]

More specifically, I tend to use the Stack Widget, so I would like to add something like 'Wrap with Stack' based on 'Wrap with Row' or 'Wrap with Column'.

Answer (score 1):

Go to File ==> Setting ==> Intentions ==> and put a mark on Dart ==> Quick assist powered by the Dart Analysis Server.
Then Apply and Okay